Trigger GCP Vertex AI from EKS pod using Workload Identity Federation
I have a project in GCP which interacts with Vertex AI (specifically with gemini-1.5-flash-001 model. I've used the default "Get Code" option in the Vertex AI studio and want to use this script in python:
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-aiplatform
gcloud auth application-default login

import base64
import vertexai
from vertexai.generative_models import GenerativeModel, Part, FinishReason
import vertexai.preview.generative_models as generative_models

def generate():
  vertexai.init(project="project1", location="us-west1")
  model = GenerativeModel(
    "gemini-1.5-flash-001",
  )
  responses = model.generate_content(
      ["""context"""],
      generation_config=generation_config,
      safety_settings=safety_settings,
      stream=True,
  )

  for response in responses:
    print(response.text, end="")


generation_config = {
    "max_output_tokens": 8192,
    "temperature": 1,
    "top_p": 0.95,
}

safety_settings = {
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
}

generate() 

(GCP default code to run vertex ai)
I've created a service account for this resource usage, with relevant roles assigned to it.
I also have an EKS cluster that runs a specific pod who's supposed to interact with this GCP project and Vertex AI resource. I want to implement the Workload Identity Federation method in order not to maintain keys/tokens from service accounts.
The following steps were made:

Created a pool, with aws as a provider.
For this pool, i've used the "GRANT ACCESS" option and there - chose the "Grant access using Service Account impersonation". After choosing the service account the aws_role attribute was chosed, and there i've provided the iam role that the eks pod is using as a service account there (there=in aws). Got an option to download the config file, and then exported an env var under the name:

$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/config/file.json

Tried to trigger my python but it couldn't be authenticated. I'm getting both 401 and 403 errors.
Worth mentioning that i've also tried on step 2 the option "Grant access using federated identities (Recommended)", downloaded the config file and changed the env. var content to THIS config file. No luck there as well.
Can anyone please explain what am i doing wrong? how can i fix this issue?
I would appreciate any help here :)
